# How can I find such string in linear time using the suffix tree?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, suffix-tree

Given a string s of length n, find the longest string t that occurs both forwards and backwards in s. 
e.g, s = yabcxqcbaz, then return t = abc or t = cba

I am considering using the generalized suffix tree but I think it would take me O(n^2) time.

```
i = 0 # Initialize the position on the S
j = 0 # Initialize the position on the Sr
n = len(S) # n is the length of the string
maxLengthPos = (0, 0) # Record the maximum length of such substring found so far and its position

# Iterate through every 
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        maxL, pos = maxLengthPos
        l = LCE(i, j) # The longest common extension which take O(1) time
        if l > maxL:
            maxLength = (l, i)
```

Can I implement it in O(n) time?

Comment: You definitely want to use a suffix tree? You can use dynamic programming and it can be done in O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) of s and its reverse. This can indeed be solved using the generalized suffix array or suffix tree of s and reverse(s), in linear time.

There's a conceptionally simpler approach using the [suffix automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_automaton) of s though. A suffix automaton is a finite automaton that matches exactly the suffixes of a string, and it can be built in linear time. You can find an implementation in C++ [in my Github repository](https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/suffix_automaton.cpp). Now you just feed the second string (in this case reverse(s)) into the automaton and record the longest match, which corresponds to the LCS of the two strings.

Comment: @BrentWashburne It's non-trivial 60 lines of code, so I don't think I can present it concisely. I will try to give a high-level overview though.

Comment: While you answered the question (yes, it's possible in linear time), an excellent answer would include a discussion of the algorithm and not just a link.  I've seen answers that are much longer than 60 lines, so don't let that be a limitation.